# Is it possible to change the text of a GUI button after it is declared?

Tags: user-interface, button, text, autoit

I have a GUI that contains buttons and one of them calculates a percentage. I have that percentage displaying in a label, but I'd like it to update the percentage ON THE BUTTON TEXT instead of a label.

I've tried but it disables the button once it changes the text. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to change button text after creation, using [`GUICtrlSetData()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetData.htm).

Affected source code is required in order for described issues to be solved.